# Modes of Convergence, Real Analysis Folland, Ch 2 Problem 39

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost uniformly, then $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. and in measure.

---

Proof: Since $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost uniformly, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a measurable set $F$ with $\mu(F) < \epsilon$ such that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $X\setminus E$.

I am not sure where to go from here, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $f_n \to f $ almost uniformly on each $E_n $, then $f_n \to f $ pointwise on $\bigcup_n E_n $ (why?). How does that help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f_n$ converges almost uniformly, for any $\delta>0$, there exists a measurable set $E_\delta$ with measure less than $\delta$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $E_\delta^c$. Thus there are $E_k$ with $\mu(E_k)<1/k$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $E_k^c$.

Let $F_n=\bigcap_{k=1}^nE_k$. Then
$$
\mu(F_n)\leqslant \mu(E_n)<1/n\quad\text{and so}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(F_n)=0
$$
Since $F_1\supset\cdots\supset F_n\supset\cdots$, let $F=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$ and by Monotone class theorem
$$
\mu(F)=\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(F_n)=0
$$
For any $x\in F^c=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n^c$, there is a $N$ that $x\in E_N^c$. Since $f_n$ converges uniformly on $E_N^c$, $f_n$ converges pointwise on $E_N^c$. This proves that $f_n$ converges pointwise a.e. Also $f_n$ converges in measure since $f_n$ converges pointwise a.e.

Comment: Wouldn't it follow from the fact that $F = \cap E_k \subset E_k$ that $\mu(F) \leq \mu(E_k)<1/k$ for all $k$? Wouldn't it imply that $\mu(F) = 0$? Why did you first construct the sets $F_n$ above? Thank you.

Comment: It is more rigorous way to involve Monotone class theorem.

Comment: converges pointwise a.e. only implies convergence in measure if the sequence of functions $f_n$ and $f$ are defined on a set $E$ with finite measure, but then again it's not stated in the question posted by the OP, thus one can assume $E$ does have finite measure